# In Wireless Networks, What is IV?

Tags: networking, wpa, wpa2, wifi

I understand it is initialization vector, but what is it ? Is it appended at the beginning of each packet as a key piece? Is it used to encrypt the entire packet? What does IV do exactly?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector

Comment: right but I didn't quite understand it :S

Answer (score 0):

The IV is included in each packet and is different in each packet. It is used to generate a distinct "packet key" for each packet, the packet key consisting of the fixed master key and the initialization vector.

Comment: so it doesn't really encrypt as much as supply necessary information?

Comment: It's sent in the clear over the wire, but it does encrypt because it is part of the key. The point is to encrypt each packet with a different key.